# Mudar string para caixa alta e remover espaços em branco

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou tentando fazer um programa em Python 3 que deve transformar o texto digitado em caixa alta e remover espaços em branco. Gostaria de saber o que há de errado no meu código uma vez que ele não esta eliminando os espaços em branco. Testei dois códigos.

- Primeiro código:

  ```
  print ("-"*50)
  print ("-"*50)

  frase = input("\nEscreva uma frase: ")

  frase = frase.upper()
  frase = frase.strip()

  print ("\n",frase)


  print ("-"*50)
  print ("-"*50)
  ```
- Segundo Código

  ```
  print ("-"*50)
  print ("-"*50)

  frase = input("\nEscreva uma frase: ")

  frase = frase.upper()
  frase = frase.replace('','')

  print ("\n",frase)

  print ("-"*50)
  print ("-"*50)
  ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O primeiro só tira espaços do início e fim, do meio seria o segundo código, mas ele não está mudando nada, o código manda trocar nada por nada, ou seja, não mexe, tem que ser espaço por nada:

```
frase = input("Escreva uma frase: ")
frase = frase.upper().replace(' ','')
print("\n", frase)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/frocyC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mkytdqan-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/RemoveAllSpaces.py).

Mas se é um exercício talvez o objetivo seria fazer na mão, caractere por caractere sem usar função pronta. O que poderia até mesmo ter mais performance eventualmente porque na forma atual tem que mexer duas vezes na mesma *string*, com um laço único pode trocar o caractere e retirar espaço ao mesmo tempo. Assim:

```
frase = input("Escreva uma frase: ")
fraseNova = ""
for chr in frase:
    if chr != " ":
        fraseNova += chr.upper()
print(fraseNova)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MC8BbR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/srepfgue-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/ParseStringUpperRemoveSpace.py).

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

O método [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) remove os caracteres apenas do início e do fim de uma string.

```
string = "     a     b     ".strip()
print(string);  # 'a     b'
```

Já o método [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma string de busca e como segundo parâmetro uma string de substituição. O método substituirá *todas as ocorrências*<sup>*</sup> da string de busca pela string de substituição.

```
string = "     a     b     ".replace(' ', '-')
print(string);  # "-----a-----b-----"
```

<sup>* o 3º parâmetro define a quantidade máxima de substituição que o método fará. Se não for especificado, todas ocorrências serão substituídas. [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)</sup>

Então o seu segundo código está errado apenas porque você está pedindo para buscar por nada (`''`) e substituindo por nada (`''`). Quando o que você quer é buscar por espaços (`' '`) e substituí-los por nada (`''`).

Como o Maniero já respondeu, seu código ficaria algo como:

```
frase = input('...')
frase = frase.upper().replace(' ','')
print(frase)
```

Comment: Obrigado. me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Não coloquei na resposta pra não complicar desnecessariamente, mas se você entrar na documentação do `strip` vai ver que também pode passar parâmetros para o método e alterar seu comportamento.